# How to use TreeTagger in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, treetagger

i want to use TreeTagger module to tag POS-information on the raw corpus.

As it seems to be faster to use GPU via Google Colab, I installed TreeTagger module, but Colab codes cannot locate TreeTagger directory.

The error type is like this:
TreeTaggerError: Can't locate TreeTagger directory (and no TAGDIR specified)

Please tell me where I should uplaod the treetagger folder.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify directory:

```
treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='en', TAGDIR='treetagger/') # treetagger is the installation dir
```

**Installation in Colab.**
Follow the instructions on the [website](https://cis.lmu.de/%7Eschmid/tools/TreeTagger/).
In one cell in Colab you have to put the following (for other (not English) languages put other link for parameter files):

```
%%bash
mkdir treetagger
cd treetagger
# Download the tagger package for your system (PC-Linux, Mac OS-X, ARM64, ARMHF, ARM-Android, PPC64le-Linux).
wget https://cis.lmu.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/data/tree-tagger-linux-3.2.4.tar.gz
tar -xzvf tree-tagger-linux-3.2.4.tar.gz
# Download the tagging scripts into the same directory.
wget https://cis.lmu.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/data/tagger-scripts.tar.gz
gunzip tagger-scripts.tar.gz
# Download the installation script install-tagger.sh.
wget https://cis.lmu.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/data/install-tagger.sh
# Download the parameter files for the languages you want to process.
# list of all files (parameter files) https://cis.lmu.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/#parfiles
wget https://cis.lmu.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/data/english.par.gz
sh install-tagger.sh
cd ..
sudo pip install treetaggerwrapper
```

And in the other following cell you can check the installation:

```
>>> import pprint   # For proper print of sequences.
>>> import treetaggerwrapper
>>> #1) build a TreeTagger wrapper:
>>> tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='en', TAGDIR='treetagger/')
>>> #2) tag your text.
>>> tags = tagger.tag_text("This is a very short text to tag.")
>>> #3) use the tags list... (list of string output from TreeTagger).
>>> pprint.pprint(tags)
```